# add title tag to JavaScript generated iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Trying to add a iframe title tag title="WhatsApp" to a 3rd party generated iframe. I have tried a lot of options and either it works but errors in the chrome dev console or does not work and does not error in the chrome dev console. I'm open to other ideas

the below code works but errors in the chrome dev console

```
 <script>
$('element').text('title="Whatsapp"');
(function () {
    var options = {
        whatsapp: "+phonenumber", // WhatsApp number
        call_to_action: "Contact us via Whatsapp!", // Call to action
        position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
    };
    var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
    s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Title is an attribute, not the text of the element.

```
$('#IDofIframe').attr('title', 'Whatsapp');
```

Replace `IDofIframe` with the actual ID of the `iframe` element. Or replace `#IDofIframe` with another selector that matches the iframe.

Comment: I still get a...
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You need to load jQuery to use its functions.

Comment: All fixed, moved jQuery to the head rather then the footer. THANK! :)

Comment: You could also move this code to the footer. It just has to be after jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I jumped the gun, Still having a problem. If I add $('element').attr('title', 'Whatsapp'); and move it under jQuery and no error in the console but also no added title for the iframe.

Comment: I assumed `element` was a placeholder. You need to replace it with the correct selector for your iframe.

Comment: It still fails the audit. $('#wh-widget-send-button-iframe').attr('title', 'Whatsapp');  taken from <iframe id="wh-widget-send-button-iframe" src="https://widget.whatshelp.io/widget/wSendButton?whatsapp=...

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.10.1.min.js  would that make a difference?

Comment: No, it should work with practically any jQuery version. Is the iframe being added asynchronously? Make sure your code runs after it's added (you might need to do it in a callback function).